# Highlight all words in a long text that is in a Cell

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to develop a Find button, to mark in red "ALL" of the word that are contained in a cell.

For example If I have in my cell this text.
"Pepper had peppermint in his pocket"
it should change to this.
"**Pepper** had **pepper**mint in his pocket"

This code highlights the first word that it finds.

```vb
    Dim i As Long
    Dim oldrngrow As Long
    Dim myValue As String
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Array(TextBox1.Value)
    TextBox2.Text = UBound(arr)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr) + 1
        myValue = arr(i - 1)
        If myValue = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox ("Please Enter a Word in Textbox")
            End
        End If
        
        Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=myValue, After:=Cells(1, i), LookIn:= _
            xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, MatchByte:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
            
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                GoTo skip
            End If
            
            oldrngrow = rng.Row
            Do While rng.Column = i
                If ComboBox1.Text = "Red" Then
                    rng.Characters(InStr(rng, myValue), Len(myValue)).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    Set rng = Cells.FindNext(After:=rng)
                    
                If oldrngrow = rng.Row Then
            Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
    skip:
    Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  After some research, I’ve put together the following code to demonstrate how to highlight every instance of a word in a string within a cell.  For the sake of the demonstration, it uses an Input Box to get the desired string-to-highlight (you can change the method), and assumes the range to search is simply A1 – again you can change this to whatever you want.

Make sure you include `Option Compare Text` at the top of the Sub – otherwise the search will be case sensitive.  Let me know how you go.

```
Option Compare Text
Sub StringColor()

Dim myRange As Range, myCell As Range, myString As String, myCount As Integer
Set myRange = Range("A1")

myString = InputBox("Type the word you want to color in A1")

For Each myCell In myRange
    For myCount = 1 To Len(myCell) - Len(myString) + 1
        If Mid(myCell, myCount, Len(myString)) = myString Then
            myCell.Characters(myCount, Len(myString)).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next myCount
Next myCell

End Sub
```